# Removing rows where there is a value match

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

```
def remove_low_data_states(column_name):
    items = df[column_name].value_counts().reset_index()
    items.columns = ['place', 'value']
    print(f'Items in column: [{column_name}] with low data')
    return list(items[items['value'].apply(lambda val: val < items.value.median())].place)

remove_low_data_states('col1') -- > returns ['hello', 'bye']
```

Orignal table

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello | 2 | 4 |
| world | 2 | 4 |
| bye | 2 | 4 |

Updated table

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| world | 2 | 4 |

The above method gives me a list of names within a column that do not pass the median criteria. How can I then use the list of names to go and remove the rows that are associated with the row value ??

I have tried using `pd.drop` but that is not to helpful, or I am making some sort of mistake.

Comment: Do you simply want to select the rows where there is not a match? `df[~df['col1'].isin(matches)]` should do it.

Comment: @user5002062 Oh, I didn't read the comments before posting. I used the same logic. If you want, I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.isin()`

```py
def remove_low_data_states(column_name):
    items = df[column_name].value_counts().reset_index()
    items.columns = ['place', 'value']
    print(f'Items in column: [{column_name}] with low data')
    return list(items[items['value'].apply(lambda val: val < items.value.median())].place)

df = df[~df['col1'].isin(remove_low_data_states('col1'))]

df.head()
```